# Processing csv in Python lists using lists and for loops

Tags: python, list, csv, for-loop, nested

I have a csv I am reading from and am making 4 lists from the first 4 columns of that csv.

```
listofcelebs = (columns['name'])
listOfImages = (columns['image'])
listOfProfessions = (columns['profession'])
listOfBestWork = (columns['bestWork'])
```

I only need to read the items from the first list to run a twitter sentiment analysis on each item and print out the result. However I would like to print out the other lists inbetween as well.

How could I print out

the the first item of the list listofcelebs,

then the first item of list listOfImages,

then the first item of list listOfProfessions,

then the first item of list listOfBestWork,

then the result of the twitter sentiment analysis on the first item of list listofcelebs,

a sperator ie. "--------------------------------------------------------------------- \n  "

then the the second item of the list listofcelebs,

then the first item of list listOfImages,

etc. etc.

In the end I store the results in a new csv with the headings [name,image,profession,bestWork,overallSentiment])

---

Here is my code currently gives the error incorrect indentation

```
import csv
import twittersearch
from collections import defaultdict

c = csv.writer(open("celebritiesBornTodayWithSentiment.csv", "wb"))
columns = defaultdict(list) # each value in each column is appended to a list

with open('celebritiesBornToday.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f) # read rows into a dictionary format
    for row in reader: # read a row as {column1: value1, column2: value2,...}
        for (k,v) in row.items(): # go over each column name and value 
            columns[k].append(v) # append the value into the appropriate list
                                 # based on column name k

listofcelebs = (columns['name'])
listOfImages = (columns['image'])
listOfProfessions = (columns['profession'])
listOfBestWork = (columns['bestWork'])

zippedListofCelebInfo = zip(listOfNames, listOfImages, listOfProfessions, listOfBestWork)

#giving headings to the columns of the final csv file
c.writerow(['name','image','profession','bestWork','overallSentiment'])


for name in zippedListofCelebInfo:
    #Printing the Name of the Celebrity
    print "Name of the celebrity: "+name

    #Printing the Image of the Celebrity
    print "Image: "+image

    #Printing the Profession of the Celebrity
    print "Profession: "+profession

    #Printing the BestWork of the Celebrity
    print "BestWork: "+bestWork

    #calling twittersearch2 from the other file to derive tweet sentiment, celebrity's full name used as the query
    overallSentiment = twittersearch.twittersearch2(name)
    print "Overall Sentiment on Twitter : "+overallSentiment

     # End of Celebrity Details
    print "--------------------------------------------------------------------- \n  "

    #saving the name, image, profession, bestWork, overallSentiment of the celebrity into a csv file
    c.writerow([name,image,profession,bestWork,overallSentiment])
```

Comment: Is there a reason to build the separate lists at all? When you're iterating over the rows of the original CSV file, you could simply print out the things you're looking for right then.

Comment: I am new to python If you could show me how to do this ie just print the overallSentiment to the fifth column. That would be nice

Comment: This was just my idea of how I could do this if there is an easier way feel free to tell me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I commented, you already are all ready iterating over each row of the input file, so it may make sense to write the new row (with the additional data item) to the output immediately after reading it, rather than storing all your data in a bunch of lists:

```
import csv
import twittersearch

with open('celebritiesBornToday.csv', "rb") as in_f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(in_f)
    with open("celebritiesBornTodayWithSentiment.csv", "wb") as out_f:
        writer = csv.DictWriter(out_f, reader.fieldnames + ["overallSentiment"])
        for row in reader:
            row["overallSentiment"] = twittersearch.twittersearch2(row["name"])
            writer.writerow(row)

            print "Name of the celebrity:", row["name"]
            print "Image:", row["image"]
            print "Profession: ", row["profession"]
            print "BestWork:", row["bestWork"]
            print "Overall Sentiment on Twitter:", row["overallSentiment"]
```

That's a whole lot shorter and simpler than your current code!

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that your lists has same length you can use `zip` function or for long list as a better choice you can use [`itertools.izip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip) to zip your list together :

```
from itertools import izip

my_lists=[listofcelebs,listOfImages ,listOfProfessions ,listOfBestWork]
for i,j,k,z in izip(*my_lists):
   print (i,j,k,z)
   print "--------------------------------------------------------------------- \n "
```

And for small list :

```
my_lists=[listofcelebs,listOfImages ,listOfProfessions ,listOfBestWork]
for i,j,k,z in zip(*my_lists):
   print (i,j,k,z)
   print "--------------------------------------------------------------------- \n "
```

If you want to print in each line :

```
my_lists=[listofcelebs,listOfImages ,listOfProfessions ,listOfBestWork]
for i,j,k,z in zip(*my_lists):
   print i,'\n',j,'\n',k,'\n',z,'\n'
   print "--------------------------------------------------------------------- \n "
```

Comment: The lists are all contain only 10 items.

Comment: @Xsyoa so you can use `zip`, that is more efficient in for smallest lists!

Comment: I am using Zip now : zippedListofCelebInfo = zip(listOfNames, listOfImages, listOfProfessions, listOfBestWork)

Comment: Could you show me how to use a for loop to print out the output in the desired way? (look at my edited question)